# How to cast 'object' with a 'Class' type in objc?

Tags: objective-c, class

```
Class cellClass=NSClassFromString(cellIdentifier);
cellClass* cell=(cellClass*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithidentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

I tried this,but it didn't work.Anyone helps?

Comment: We need more context.  Can the relevant classes conform to a common protocol?  Is a raw `-performSelector` not good enough?  Do you need compile-time type-checking?  What exactly are you trying to do, and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not use cellClass* as code itself. this will not work!!

try some methods from cellClass. f.e.:

`[cellClass newObject]` or something like that.

Comment: thx Mr Q.C. I want to use methods in cellClass , I don't know how to find the methods without cast cell to cellClass.